# Microsoft.Build.CentralPackageVersions and folder structure

Tags: .net, msbuild, asp.net-core-3.1

Hello ALl I want to structure my project such that

```
 | Build
        Packages.props 
 | Output
 | Source
        Project1-Folder
                  Project1.csproj
        Project2-Folder
                  Project2.csproj
 Sln 
 Directory.Build.props
```

with Packages.props in this structure, it can't be recognized project 1, or 2 , but if I moved it to the root it works fine. any idea how to make it works under this structure

I tried using Directory props , but it gives circular error
my Directory.Build.props looks like

```
<Project>   
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EnableCentralPackageVersions>true</EnableCentralPackageVersions>
    <CentralPackagesFile>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Build\Packages.props</CentralPackagesFile> 
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

and packages.prop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Update="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the path to the `Packages.props` file through the `CentralPackagesFile` property. So you could add the following to your `.csproj` files:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <CentralPackagesFile>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\Build\Packages.props</CentralPackagesFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Instead of adding this to every project separately, you can also create a `Directory.Build.props` file to your project with the following contents:

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <CentralPackagesFile>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Build\Packages.props</CentralPackagesFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that you will have to place this `Directory.Build.props` file either in the root directory, or in your `Source/` directory in order to have it picked up.

Comment: Hi @poke I updated my question, it give circualar error can you help me with this please

Comment: @Ali Sorry, I used the wrong variable for the `Directory.Build.Props` file. It should use `MSBuildThisFileDirectory` for building the path. When I try this out, it works for me with your folder setup.